# Cannot Draw Polygons in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, polygon, polyline

I have a Google Maps API file I'm trying to draw polylines and polygons in. However when I input the code for drawing these, I get an error in Google Chrome saying 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input' for my closing script bracket (< /script>).

Here is my code:

```
<script>

  var map;
  function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    //center on the US
    center: {lat: 39.8283, lng: -98.5795},
    zoom: 5
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var sampleCounty = [
    {lat: 32.344437, lng: -86.496774},
    {lat: 32.402814, lng: -86.717897},
    {lat: 32.340803, lng: -86.814912},
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var samplePolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: sampleCounty,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
  });

  //place polygon in map
    samplePolygon.setMap(map);

  //make HTML element change color when polygon is hovered over
  google.maps.event.addListener(samplePolygon, 'mouseover', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("sampleDescription").style.color = "blue";
  });

  //make HTML element change color when polygon is not hovered over
  google.maps.event.addListener(samplePolygon, 'mouseout', function (event) {
    document.getElementById("sampleDescription").style.color = "red";
});

</script><!--end google maps API-->
<!--api link here--><script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

In my code my API key is there. Does anyone know why this is happening/how to fix it?

Comment: Use a good IDE or paste your code in an online Javascript validator which will tell you what the problems are.

Answer (score -1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. missing close `}` on the `initMap` function (causes `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` error).
2. `&callback=initAutocomplete` in the script include (causes `"initAutocomplete is not a function"` error), there is no `initAutocomplete` function in your code, that should be `initMap`.

If I change those and add the required HTML/CSS, it works.

[image: screenshot of working map]

**working code snippet:** (note I also changed the center and zoom so you can see the polygon)

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    //center on the US
    center: {
      lat: 32.402814,
      lng: -86.717897
    },
    zoom: 10
  });

  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var sampleCounty = [{
      lat: 32.344437,
      lng: -86.496774
    },
    {
      lat: 32.402814,
      lng: -86.717897
    },
    {
      lat: 32.340803,
      lng: -86.814912
    },
  ];

  // Construct the polygon.
  var samplePolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: sampleCounty,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
  });

  //place polygon in map
  samplePolygon.setMap(map);

  //make HTML element change color when polygon is hovered over
  google.maps.event.addListener(samplePolygon, 'mouseover', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("sampleDescription").style.color = "blue";
  });

  //make HTML element change color when polygon is not hovered over
  google.maps.event.addListener(samplePolygon, 'mouseout', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("sampleDescription").style.color = "red";
  });
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```